# Allowing a filename as aController Action

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Who can I use one particular filename (id: myfile.gif) as a controller action? What about the route definition.

TIA, /Luis

Comment: What exactly are you asking? I'm voting this to be closed because I find it unclear what you're asking.

Comment: What are you trying to do ? all the static file requests will be usually handled by IIS.

Comment: If you put the file in your MVC project, then it will already be accessible. E.g. if you put it in folder `Content` -> `http://server/Content/myfile.gif`. If the file does not reside in your project, then the answer by @Douglas Gandini could be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is based on "how to handle/map a static file in a controller/action".

- Create an action to handle your request
- Create a new route pointing to your action
- Configure a new handler in your web.config telling to IIS to pass the request to the managed code

Action:

```
[HttpGet]
public FileContentResult Index(string FileName) {
var content = ... // your file content retrieve logic
return File(content, "image/gif");
}
```

Route Mapping:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Image",
    url: "SomePath/{filename}.gif",
    defaults: new { controller = "Image", action = "Index" }
        );
```

Handler:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="Giffiles" path="*.gif" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. ... now I can track anything I want: sent and opened emails, twitter, linkedin, facebook posts, .... anything :D